# SQL: How to write SQL to extract minimum/maximum value for each unique pair?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table like this:

[image: Table Transportation]

The table records all methods and fares from one station to another.
I want to find out the maximum/minimum price from one station to all the others, how can I do so using SQL?

I want to achieve something like this:
(finding the minimum fares for all the unique pairs)

[image: Expected Result]

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint : `GROUP BY` & `MIN()`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using ms-access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just aggregate function `min()`

```
select [from],[to],min(fare) from table_name
group by [from],[to]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It solves my problem easily. I've tried using natural join originally.